# iPhone 5s GSM - unknown error 2006 on restoring the iPhone, stuck in recovery mode

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore, ios

My phone is iPhone 5s GSM. I tried to go back from iOS 11 to iOS 10.3.3 and this happens. Now, I am stuck with apparently a bricked phone. Things that I tried:
1. Going to recovery mode in iTunes and doing the restore (I guess this automatically goes to the last iOS version, so 11). Result is 2006 error
2. Going to recovery mode in iTunes, option+click the restore button and choosing the .ipsw file of iOS 10.3.3. Result is 2006 error.
3. Going to DFU mode, option+click the restore button and choosing the .ipsw file of iOS 10.3.3. Result is 200 error.
4. Goind to .....Library/iPhone Software Updates directory and deleting it. Retrying the restore through iTunes. Same result.
What else can I try guys, I am getting desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by pushing it out of Recovery mode cycle by using ReiBoot (https://www.tenorshare.com/products/reiboot.html). I am sure there are some other apps that can do this too. It's very simple to do, I just installed it, run it, plug the iPhone in computer via USB. It detects the iPhone, offers a "push out of recovery mode" button of sort. Click the button and voila!

Comment: It's helpful if you explain ***how*** you did this rather than a single line referencing a third party tool and where you shared it (without a link)

Comment: You mean like that? I don't understand.

Comment: Links to the utilities you use help.